# Error sharing layer package (.lpk)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, layer-package

it was my understanding that creating an .lpk combined the symbology AND source data of a geography into one file for easy sharing.

However, upon creating the .lpk here in the office, the field techs are unable to open the .lpk whilst OFF of our network but open it while ON the network connection.

I am wondering if it is possible there are some sharing permissions made behind the scenes by our Network Admins or DBAs that could be causing this?

I am happy to provide more context but wanted to start with the simple first.

When looking at data source, the .lpk is referencing the machine and .gdb that the .lpk was created from:

\wpdotfill10\r_vmp13_userseng****hwye16a****ArcGIS\Packages\HOSESITES_NS_HPMS_REG_2_CCC571DB-1478-412C-8A15-2A432F7AEBA9\v105\hosesite_cleanup_2019.gdb

[image]

Comment: Are you using ArcMap to create your LPK?  What are you using to extract that package?

Comment: Hi PolyGeo - yes I am using ArcMap 10.5 - I've used the .lpk wizard where you right click the layer and run through the steps. I've also tried using the Data Management Tools>Package>Create Layer Package tool in the ArcToolbox and they both yield the same results

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: Something strange here. I'd suspect if the data was referenced in the package (vs. copied), the package would load and you'd have broken data links. NOT an error about invalid package _before_ ArcMap opens.